# TypeScript class decorator to create method with same typed arguments as constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, decorator

In ES6 classes, I find myself creating static `create` methods, prefering to do `ClassName.create()` rather than `new ClassName()` or `new ClassName`, since I have run into some silly errors having to do with accessing properties on the newly created object; slipping up and doing `new ClassName.methodCall()` instead of `(new ClassName).methodCall()`. IMO it's cleaner to do `ClassName.create().methodCall()` and less prone to silly and difficult-to-catch errors.

However, it gets tedious and verbose to do this on every class, so I was wondering if there was a way to use TS/ES6 decorators so that I could do

```js
@Creatable // or @Creatable()
class ClassName {
    constructor(arguments: IArguments) {}
}
```

which would create a `static create(arguments: IArguments) { return new this(arguments); }` method on the class, with the same arguments, including types.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: extends Creatable; class Creatable { create(args...){ var obj=Object.create(this); this.constructor.call(this,...args);return obj;}}

Comment: forgot to mention I would like to have it type safe, will edit the question

Comment: Actually `new ClassName(…).methodCall()` works just fine. It's only when you omit the constructor argument list (`new ClassName.methodCall()`) that you need to group it into `(new ClassName).methodCall()`.

Comment: @Jonasw Don't use inheritance for this (also your method doesn't do what the OP wants)

Comment: Seems you're right about that, where I had issues there were no arguments. I will update the question, because regardless I would like to use the `.create()` pattern

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to easily add new methods to classes with decorators in TypeScript, there's [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) for that.

Doing that will require to use type assertions, something like:

```
interface ICreatable<T> extends Function {
  new (): T;
  create: (...args) => T;
}

function Creatable() {
  return function (target) {
    target.create = (...args) => new target(...args);
    return target;
  }
}

@Creatable()
class Foo {...}

(<ICreatable<Foo>>Foo).create(...)
```

Considering the problem statement, this is XY problem. While omitted constructor parentheses are the real problem.

The trouble-free way to instantiate classes with and without arguments is

```
new Foo().bar();
new Foo(1).bar();
```

And not

```
(new Foo).bar();
```

Optional constructor parentheses are often considered bad manners and banned in style guides. If a habit causes problems, it can be considered bad habit and should be avoided. Just don't do that. There's no real need for `create` factory method here.

Comment: Will take your advice on just using parens after the class name. I will clarify the question though, because I'm still interested; it doesn't really matter to me if it's `@Creatable` or `@Creatable()`

Comment: The first part of the answer addresses that. It's impractical to do that with decorators in TS, as you can see.